# Copy (Rsync) only files from subirectories

Tags: shell, rsync, cp

I'd be really happy about some help. Lets imagine a snapshot of a directory structure:

```
../test1/test6/test62.txt
../test1/test6/test65.txt
../test1/test6/test67.txt
../test1/test6/test69.txt
../test1/test6/test60.txt
../test1/test6/test68.txt
../test1/test6/test63.txt
../test1/test6/test66.txt
../test1/test6/test64.txt
../test1/test6/test61.txt
../test2/test1/test2.txt
../test2/test1/test9.txt
../test2/test1/test1.txt
../test2/test1/test6.txt
../test2/test1/test3.txt
../test2/test1/test8.txt
../test2/test1/test4.txt
../test2/test1/test10.txt
../test2/test1/test5.txt
../test2/test1/test7.txt
```

My end goal is to copy all the .txt files in one new directory ( e.g target ).

There are many more directories in reality.

I found a very nice cp command:

```
cp ../**/**/*.txt .
```

But there is an issue. It's a lot of files, like 250GB of images, so cp errors with:

```
Argument list too long
```

I read a bit about how to do it with rsync, which seems the right way, but I can't wrap my head around writing the command and what to exactly exclude and include.

Comment: Do you really want to copy, or would moving or linking be more useful? Makes no significant difference to the resulting command but can make a massive difference on the total disk space used

Comment: How do you want to handle name collisions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little strange having all the directory paths start with `..`. Personally I'd recommend you go up a level and copy/move/link the files into the nominated child directory.

However, this will allow for the `..` and ensure you don't end up trying to copy files that have previously been copied

```
find ../ -mindepth 3 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cp --target-directory . -- {} +
```

You can drop in `ln` for `cp` if linking is sufficient instead of copying. Likewise `mv` if moving is the desired intent. Use `cp -p` if you want to try and keep permissions, timestamps, etc.

Note that if you have two or more files with the same name, all but the last copied will be overwritten. If you're using `mv` all but the last will be lost. If you're using `ln` only the first will be successfully linked.

Answer (score -1):

I found one possible solution that works. It's using find with rsync:

```
find ../. -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rsync -av {} . \;
```

Comment: That's close but you'll potentially end up trying to copy files you've already copied